# Mentioning a user in slack depending on git commit

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to be able to mention specific users in a slack message if they have broken a build/failed unit tests based on their last commit.

I am able to get the git username of the person by using the following:

```
environment {
    AUTHOR_NAME = bat (
        script: "git show -s --format='%%an' HEAD",
        returnStdout: true
    ).split('\r\n')[2].trim()        
}
```

And I can view this by using

```
    stage('do things') {
        steps {
            echo "The last commit was written by ${AUTHOR_NAME}."
        }
    }
```

Which returns The last commit was written by 'my-id'.

So I thought it would be quite easy to send a message to me.

```
if (${AUTHOR_NAME} == "my-id") {
    SLACK_USER = '@userId'
} else {
    SLACK_USER = '@anotherUserId'
}
```

However, the message always goes to the @anotherUserId account.

I have enclosed the whole if statement into a script block, but still no word.

I know this should be easy, but having some real issues here.  Using the pipeline (declerative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must quote the variable into double quotes (generating a GString)

```
if ("${AUTHOR_NAME}" == "my-id") {
```

or remove the dollar and braces characters

```
if (AUTHOR_NAME == "my-id") {
```

Comment: I had tried both your suggestions, to be sure tried them again, however still nothing.
I've had to put a script {} block around everything and even printed out in the console what it sees

Comment: `steps {
                echo "AUTHOR_NAME is >${AUTHOR_NAME}<"                                
                script {
                    if ("${AUTHOR_NAME}" == "my-id") {                      
                        echo "true"
                    } else {
                        echo "false"
                    }
                }
                echo "commit - ${COMMIT_TITLE}"
            }`

Comment: Ok I have found why it was failing, somehow the text "my-id" was being set with single quotes around it (so 'my-id' - which of course wouldn't match my-id without.